# apply median on multiple intervals of a vector

Tags: r

I have a numeric vector `x` and a data.frame `startEnd` including columns with starting rows and ending rows.

```
> head(x)
23.80077 23.72072 23.64067 23.56062 23.48056 23.40051

> head(startEnd)
  rowStart rowEnd
1       43    435
2      486    887
3      898   1325
4     1327   1742
5     1757   2196
6     2220   2646
```

I would like to calculate the median of the vector `x` from each rowStart to the repsective rowEnd. I already have a working solution:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(startEnd)){
    x_median[i] = median(x[startEnd$rowStart[i]:startEnd$rowEnd[i]])
}
```

I could easily transer it to apply, but I am searching for a more efficient way. I also thought about splitting the vector to a list by using the intervals and then applying median on each list element. Any recommendations?

Comment: maybe you can use `purrr:map2`

Comment: In base R you could use `mapply` / `Map` but not sure if will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- rnorm(3000) + 23
startEnd <- data.frame(
  rowStart = c(43L, 486L, 898L, 1327L, 1757L, 2220L),
  rowEnd = c(435L, 887L, 1325L, 1742L, 2196L, 2646L)
)

mapply(function(s, e) {median(x[s:e])}, startEnd[["rowStart"]], startEnd[["rowEnd"]])

# [1] 23.12682 23.10009 22.99902 22.99883 23.08723 23.01746
```